# Как задать высоту окна NSWindow выше, чем высота экрана

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

Привет! У меня проблема, помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть у меня окно, которое меняет свою высоту в зависимости от контента. При запуске программы все нормально, высота окна выставляется нормально, но если в процессе изменения контента высота окна должна поменяться, то окно автоматически стает по высоте меньше, чем высота екрана и часть контента делается невидимой.

Попытка сделать высоту окна через setFrame большей, чем высота экрана, ничего не дает.

Как задать высоту окна больше, чем высота экрана?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас высота _контента_ больше высоты экрана?

Comment: да, бывают такие ситуации, когда высота контента должна быть больше чем высота экрана. В моем случае это окно с вертикальными вкладками которые открываються. И если открыть все вкладки, то высота окна больше 700 пикселей и тогда, например, на макбуке 13 окно должно быть больше чем экран, но оно уменьшается автоматически и контент обрезается.

Comment: Вы просто физически не можете поставить размер окна больше размера экрана. Для таких ситуаций есть NSScrollVew.

Comment: но при запуске программы, если контент выше чем высота экрана, то окно не обрезается и не подгоняется размер автоматически, а как раз такое как нужно (уходит вниз за границу экрана)

Comment: Хм. Да, был не прав - действительно такое возможно. Покажите код, где вы растягиваете окно.

Comment: Вот окно при старте http://d.pr/pk5U а вот после того как я спрячу одну вкладку и снова открою http://d.pr/pmXT в этом случае высота окна почему-то не меняется, окно центруется и контент обрезается

Comment: а вот метод, который определяет нужный размер окна и меняет его http://d.pr/xK8c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

подсказали ответ на сайте http://stackoverflow.com

Нужно создать подкласс от NSWindow и в него добавить метод:

```
- (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen
{
  //return the unaltered frame, or do some other interesting things
  return frameRect;
}
```